# android mediaplayer replacement for setAudioStreamType not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In this app, the sound must come from the earpiece speaker. This was working with `MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL)`, until I updated the targetSdk to 27 and some devices with OS version > 25 started ignoring this. 
I found out later that `MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType` went deprecated but the new way of doing it isn't working.

```
AudioAttributes attr = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
                        .build();

mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
    getContext(),
    Uri.parse(mAudioMedia),
    null,
    attr,
    AudioManager.AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: sorry, I didn't. I remember I ended up with a different implementation, but I can't even remember what was.